# Number of unique elements of polynomial

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials

Consider the polynomial function

$$\sum_{k=1}^{N}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{I}x_i\right)^k$$

Here $N$ and $I$ are positive integers. Is there a general formula for the number of unique elements of this polynomial? For example when $N=k=2$, there are five unique elements: $x_1,x_2,x_1^2,x_2^2,x_1x_2$.

Comment: For each fixed $k$, the answer will be the number of compositions of $k$ into $I$ parts.

Comment: @GregMartin Doesn't seem right to me. Can you elaborate?

Comment: It will certainly be the same as one less than the number of terms of $(1+x_1+\cdots+x_I)^N,$ which will be the same as one less than  the number of terms of $(x_0+x_1+\cdots+x_I)^N.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When expanding out $(x_1+\dots+x_I)^k$, every monomial looks like
$$
\frac{k!}{m_1!m_2!\cdots m_I!} x_1^{m_1}\cdots x_{I}^{m_I},
$$
where $(m_1,\dots,m_I)$ is a list of nonnegative integers for which $$m_1+\dots+m_I=k.$$
Using stars and bars, there are
$$
\binom{k+I-1}{I-1}
$$
ways to choose the list $(m_1,\dots,m_I)$. Summing from $k=1$ to $k=N$, and using the hockey stick identity, the total number of monomials is
$$
\sum_{k=1}^N \binom{k+I-1}{I-1}=\binom{N+I}{I}-1.
$$
For example, with $N=I=2$, my formula gives $\binom{2+2}{2}-1=5$, confirming what you found.